Add webex meeting invitation to outlook calendar
when I receive a Webex meeting invitation, in some cases I see it like in the first screenshot and when I accept the invitation it automatically will be saved in my calendar. But in some cases for any reason I see it just as a dashed line (screenshot 2) and when I accept the meeting no calendar-entry will be created. I just have no clue about the reason, could someone help?
BR


